# AngularJS not compiling html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.message = '<p>test text</p>';
var html = '<div>{{::message}}</div>';

$scope.$apply(function () {
    $compile(html)($scope, function (cloned, scope) {
        $compile(cloned)(scope, function (clonedTwo, scopeTwo) {
            angular.element(myDiv).append(clonedTwo);
        });
    });
});
```

This results in a div element showing the following:

[image]

I realize that when I compile it it does it correctly. However when I try and compile it a second time it has no effect.

To fix this I need to compile the template and return raw html then use that html in the second compile.

Is there a method in angular which just renders plain html?

Answer (score 2):

The method I was looking for was `$interpolate`.

```
$scope.message = '<p>test text</p>';
var html = '<div>{{::message}}</div>';

var inter = $interpolate(html)($scope);

$scope.$apply(function () {
    $compile(inter)($scope, function (cloned, scope) {
        angular.element(myDiv).append(cloned);
    });
});
```